# Rails application puma server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am creating a chat application (using puma server with max thread count 20 and wen concurrency 5). In this application the message after being sent by the user that gets saved and appends at receivers side through socket. But if the user types more messages faster the messages order changes. How to get saved the records in an order

Comment: u just need to make for every channel own table and custom class for it.

Comment: I don't get you. Can you please elaborate, FYI I am using aws iot

Comment: Did you [consider using a native WebSocket / SSE solution instead of a `hijack` based solution](https://bowild.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/rubys-rack-push-decoupling-the-real-time-web-application-from-the-web/)? Maybe look at [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io) or other similar approaches (I'm the author).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using push / polling technologies (SSE / WebSockets / AJAX) to receive chat data, consider adding a millisecond based timestamp to the messages.

This will allow you to order the messages on the client side using the exact timestamp built to each message and prevent message ordering issues.

Also, minimizing the server processing time per message will minimize scheduling issues.

This includes choosing a faster technology / solution as well as increasing concurrency or separating the database storage "event" from the "push" event handling scheme (which is usually unnecessary and less ideal, but it does offer higher reaction time).